# Is there some way to delete session info from address line when redirecting?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, browser, jboss

I am using Wildfly, Spring MVC in my project.
And after redirecting to another page of my project - to my browser address line appears some session info like in this image:
[image]

p.s. When i were using Tomcat - there was no such problems. 
Is there an optimal way to stop auto-adding session information in the address bar?
Thanks.

**Update:**

In the normal situation, when i were redirecting in my past projects(for example) from page "index" to page "login" i saw something like this: "myapp.com/login"
But now i saw:"myapp.com/login;jsessionid=nGTE5tfW3hUZZOP1yQTF4Mrh3PRbNu8UyY8UBkmx.coderunit".
I didn't made some special options to my app server to cancel this session info additions. Maybe there are some special tool for it.

Comment: You want to hide the jsessionid from the url in your question?

Comment: Yes.  I want to hide all additional info about session, is it possible ?

Comment: There is no need already. 
I had add this special config to my web.xml:
<session-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
 </session-config>
 and it helped me.
Thanks Perdomoff.

Comment: Thanks :) if you do not mind, i added my own answer for this issue. Maybe  it can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. 
There is some spectial option for web.xml.

This is the default behavior of a servlet container. If the client doesn’t include a cookie in the first request, the container cannot tell whether the client supports cookies or not. Therefore the container embeds the session id in the URL.

You can disable this in your web.xml using the session-config element:

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

It helped me. Good luck.